# MS Access conversion

Tags: jquery, html, web-services, ms-access, reporting-services

I have been tasked with converting an existing MS Access 2007 application into a web application. The data is currently stored in a SQL Server 2005 database. As I have practically no web development experience I want to be careful of how I proceed.

I am planning on using SSRS to handle the reports that currently exist in the Access application. As far as the user interface is concerned, I am not sure what would be the best.

I was advised to wrap all of my database calls in web services and then to look into learning jquery, javascript, and HTML 5. What do you think?

Comment: might consider [ASP.NET Dynamic Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ee845452.aspx) for building a web [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) interface.

Comment: Are you going to be doing any more web based projects in the future.  Do you have the time to learn the latest technologies or is this just a quick and dirty small scale application?

Comment: I am going to be learning and doing more web projects in the future

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you use Access 2010? Access 2010 allows web publishing. The forms you build in Access are converted to .net zammel (XAML) forms. The code in a Access form is converted to JavaScript and runs local in the browser. (so you can write both browser side code and server side code).

And you can publish to the cloud using office 365. (however, office 365 does not yet support Access web forms). However,  accesshosting, and other providers do of course supports Access reports. (you need SharePoint).

So one possibility is to use Access 2010.

In the following short video, note how I switch to running Access 100% in the browser.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AU4mH0jPntI

No ActiveX and no Silverlight is required – so the resulting application runs just fine on my iPad.

Note that when you publish, then the data on the cloud side is not stored in Access tables anymore. And note that your Access reports are converted into SQL server reporting services format (RDL).

Depending on your infrastructure and systems you have in place, Access 2010 could be a possible choice here. And if you use office 365, then the server farm can quite much scale out to as many users since all of this works on their new cloud based OS, and is designed for cloud computing from the ground up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sticking with the Microsoft stack (IIS, SQL Server, Visual Studio) and have a bit of time to invest in learning, I would recommend looking at [ASP.Net MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) MVC for the web front end.  Lots of material out there, [TekPub](http://tekpub.com) especially good.

For your database access, EntityFramework or NHibernate are a good fit for this.  I still use Linq2Sql, however, there are other ORM's (Object Relation Mappers - to define your database in code) out there like Dapper or Massive to look at.

Get some good books and good tools ([DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/) or [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/))